# List in @FormParam of POST request of REST service is empty when size exceeds certain limit

Tags: rest, http-post, cxf, form-parameter

I have an MVC application talking to REST interface designed using CXF. I am submitting a POST request with dynamic size list as FormParam. I have seen very weird behavior. When list size exceeds certain limit,  list in FormParam is always empty. 
Is there a size limitation how big list can be sent in POST request. Below is my REST interface.

```
@POST
@Path("/addIds")
public void addIds(
        @FormParam("newStatus") Status newStatus,
        @FormParam("Ids") List<Long> Ids
);
```

Client is connecting to this interface using below configuration.

```
<jaxrs:client id="remoteInterfaceClient"
                  serviceClass="com.test.RemoteInterface"
                  username="test" 
                  password="test" 
                  address="${url}">

        <jaxrs:features>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.transport.common.gzip.GZIPFeature" />
            <cxf:logging />
        </jaxrs:features>

        <jaxrs:providers>
            <bean class=".......JacksonJaxbJsonProvider" />
        </jaxrs:providers>

    </jaxrs:client>
```

Any thoughts or suggestions where can I find relevant material to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be issue with size of data sent. I changed the REST API to below format and got it resolved. Since it is a POST API, default param type is Form Param, so need to explicitly mention them, Just had to mention newStatus as QueryParam since I am sending it in url.

```
@POST
@Path("/addIds")
public void addIds(
        @QueryParam("newStatus") Status newStatus, List<Long> Ids
);
```